# Reading from console and creating class instance

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, iostream, cin

I am still learning C++ and I don't know how to do sth like that.

I have a class Student, with fields: name, id, etc.

I suppose to let the user input all the information by cin>>aStudent. This is so weird(no match in java) how I can overload >> so it will work that way?

Comment: I didnt get you .Is aStudent an object??

Comment: Follow this [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorialoperator_overloading.html) ,i hope it would solve your prob

Answer (score 1):

A naïve solution is as follows:

```
struct Student { string name; int id; … };

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Student& s) {
    return is >> s.name >> s.id >> …;
}
```

While simple, this has the disadvantage that `name` must be entered without whitespace, which is probably not what you want. In practice, you'll usually want to prompt for the fields one at a time:

```
Student s;
std::cout << "name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, s.name);
std::cout << "id  : ";
std::cin >> id;
⋮
```

Even this is oversimplified, since it doesn't handle input errors, optional termination, etc. But it should be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you need to overload `operator>>` for `istream` like

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Student& s){
   //read from stream
   return stream;
}
```

and make it a friend of Student